# How to properly install the iotivity-node npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, iotivity

I will be very specific and will divide my question into points.

I am running a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine with node.js on board

**1. What I want to achieve in overall:**

I want to install the iotivity-node npm package on my local computer

**2. What is not working:**

During the installation I get the following logs and errors:

> iotivity-node@1.2.1-1 install
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/iotivity-node node-gyp rebuild
>
> make: Entering directory
>   `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iotivity-node/build' ACTION Building CSDK
>   iotivity-installed Cloning into
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iotivity-node/iotivity-native'... remote:
>   Counting objects: 3825, done remote: Finding sources: 100% (3825/3825)
>   remote: Total 3825 (delta 281), reused 1993 (delta 281) Receiving
>   objects: 100% (3825/3825), 13.87 MiB | 365.00 KiB/s, done. Resolving
>   deltas: 100% (281/281), done. Checking connectivity... done. Note:
>   checking out '0c90ca6ffcbb6a2c56c977ec11bebb7b1d14053b'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
>   may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.
>   Example:
>
> git checkout -b new_branch_name
>
> Cloning into
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iotivity-node/iotivity-native/extlibs/tinycbor/tinycbor'...
>   error: RPC failed; result=35, HTTP code = 0 fatal: The remote end hung
>   up unexpectedly make: *** [iotivity-installed] Error 128 make: Leaving
>   directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iotivity-node/build' gyp ERR!
>   build error  gyp ERR! stack Error:`make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp
>   ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-107-generic gyp ERR! command
>   "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/iotivity-node gyp
>   ERR! node -v v6.4.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0 gyp ERR! not ok  npm
>   ERR! Linux 3.13.0-107-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "iotivity-node" npm ERR! node
>   v6.4.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! iotivity-node@1.2.1-1 install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR!
>   Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the iotivity-node@1.2.1-1
>   install script 'node-gyp rebuild'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the
>   latest version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this
>   is most likely a problem with the iotivity-node package, npm ERR! not
>   with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your
>   system: npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild npm ERR! You can get information
>   on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   iotivity-node npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their
>   info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls iotivity-node npm ERR! There is
>   likely additional logging output above.

**3. Did anyone run across this issue while installing iotivity-node and if yes how you have resolved it? Thank you in advance for your answers.**

Comment: Looks like the network problem. Does this always happen? I have installed iotivity-node on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS successfully for many times.

Comment: Looks like a temporary issue. Did you retry recently ?

Answer (score 0):

> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

This means it failed to download the code it needs. Just try again - it should work.